# CSS :before Pilcrow sign

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a pilcrow (¶) sign before an element. This code works in Safari only. The pilcrow appears.

```
.ydss-comment:before
{ 
content:"\B6\";
color:red;
font-size:1.5em;
}
```

If I replace the \B6\ with a letter or any text or number

```
content:"My Text";
```

The text appears correctly in FireFox, both Mac and PC, but no luck at all with IE.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 for teaching me what the name of that symbol is.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#pseudoelements) `:before` was only supported in IE 8.

Comment: nick there is a really interesting article on the pilcrow and other punctuation symbols here: http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/02/the-pilcrow-part-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the content to this:

```
content: '\00b6'
```

It seems that you have to specify the full 4 digits.

Also, about why it doesn't work in IE:

*(This was in [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67392/richard)'s answer which was then deleted)*

> The `:before` selector was only supported recently. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#pseudoelements) `:before` was only supported in IE 8.

Comment: Thank you. I have put that on the site. Works everywhere it seems, but still no luck in IE7 though.

Comment: IE7 not support :after & :before but you can use this hack http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: @sandeep How does your link help in any way?

Comment: @JamWaffles; read the article carefully. they write hack for IE7 & below. etc:  * html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

Comment: @sandeep read the question carefull... actually, just read it at all. It has nothing to do with clearing floats whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

In `:after` & `:before` we use hexadecimal for `special characters`.

Like this:

```
.ydss-comment:before
{ 
content:"\00b6";
}
```

Here is the table of special characters and their corresponding hexadecimal values http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/